# IE11 and the .NET User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always returns false

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0, internet-explorer-11

IE11 is unable to know when someone has logged in with Forms Authentication.

This .NET command works in IE10 and in compatibility mode with IE11:
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Test", false);

IE11 returns false to User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. It does store the authentication cookies, but it does not load the User.Identity from the authentication cookies.

Does anyone know if IE11 is dropping support for User.Identity or if I need to update IIS to identify IE11?

Update: The problem is only with .NET 4.0 sites. Any .NET 3.51 or .NET 2.0 sites work fine.

My solution was to install .NET 4.5 on the server
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: I'm a bit confused; User.Identity.IsAuthenticated looks like its from Asp.Net, not IE11.  Is your problem that IE11 no longer sending Windows authentication automatically?  If you go to IE11 settings, Advanced under Security, make sure Enabled Windows Integrated Authentication is checked.

Comment: Yes, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is part of ASP.NET and works with IE10 and below. It also works with all versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. At least for me, it doesn't with IE11 Preview.

Comment: @Steve - if you're testing out IE10 and IE11 at the same time, is there a chance that you're using two systems/VMs and authenticating differently on both?

Comment: No, I upgraded a lab computer to IE11 after a user complaint. The lab was running IE10 and was able to use .NET forms authentication, but after upgrading to IE11 the forms authentication does not work. At least the User.Identity part does not work.

Comment: Removed the downvote as the question is much clearer now.

Comment: did you look at the setting in IE11 I suggested?

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to figure out what problem IE11 was having.

Comment: Found the solution based on this question "Internet Explorer 11 does not authenticates on some of the sites"<br />
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11_pr-windows8_1_pr/internet-explorer-11-does-not-authenticates-on/47382440-71e5-4a66-ab41-1c070abbd3e5

While the exact solution did not work for me, it got me in the right direction. That is to look at .NET on the server. It seems that there are a couple of .NET updates that are keeping up with IE11.

My solution was to install .NET 4.5<br />
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: Holy molly.... how is this even happening?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this problem is related to how ASP .NET v4 handles cookies with IE11. 
Have you tried setting cookieless="UseCookies" attribute in forms element in your web.config?

Read here for more information:

[http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/aspnet-40-forms-authentication-issues-with-ie11/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188717/how-did-harmless-crawler-bypass-webforms-authentication-and-hijack-a-users-ses/)

[How did harmless crawler bypass WebForms authentication, and hijack a user's session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188717/how-did-harmless-crawler-bypass-webforms-authentication-and-hijack-a-users-ses/)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution based on this question "Internet Explorer 11 does not authenticates on some of the sites"
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11_pr-windows8_1_pr/internet-explorer-11-does-not-authenticates-on/47382440-71e5-4a66-ab41-1c070abbd3e5

While the exact solution did not work for me, it got me in the right direction. That is to look at .NET on the server. It seems that there are a couple of .NET updates that are keeping up with IE11.

My solution was to install .NET 4.5 on the server
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653